# How to get all dict keys-values in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dict like this in a function:

```
def my_func(key):
dictionary = 
    {
        'key1':
               {'some_key': 'some_val'},
        'key2':
               {'some_key': 'some_val'}
    }
return dictionary.get(key)
```

In one function1 where I call only a part of this config. So I call it like `my_func('key1')`. And I have function2, where I want to get all the dictionary. Can I get it without `for` cycle?

Comment: you can just return `dictionary` or its `items`?

Answer (score 0):

By using a recursive approach together with functional progrmaming to avoid loops:

```
dictionary = {'key1': {'some_key1': 'some_val1'}, 'key2': {'some_key2': 'some_val2'}}

def my_func(key, dictionary):
    if key in dictionary:
        return dictionary[key]
    return next(filter(None, map(lambda d: my_func(key, d) if isinstance(d, dict) else None, dictionary.values())), None)

a = my_func('some_key2', dictionary)
# some_val2

a = my_func('not a key', dictionary)  # if key is wrong
# None
```

Comment: not exactly clear on how the output should be. In case edit the question with in example of the output